# Scraping product information for comic book website

Tags: wordpress, automation, screen-scraping

I'm making a comic book website built upon a WordPress platform for an old friend for his business. I would like to be able to have a script that goes to various publisher sites and pulls in the data. I'm new to programming and I've read of many different alternatives and just don't know where to begin. Firstly, would this be legal to pull this content from these websites? Secondly, here's an example for what I would like to do.

1. Page displays what's coming out for the month. Copy all links from
   that page within the appropriate div that leads to the comic book
   details. Save each hyperlink as $comiclink or whatever. The script will
   execute each hyperlink at a time.
2. Go to the hyperlink for $comiclink and scrape content out of the page based
       upon what's in certain DIV's on that page. Example:

   - Copy & save comic title within a defined div into $title
   - Copy & save previous and future title hyperlinks within a defined div into $othertitles

     > *Note: $othertitles will loop off and start the same process itself from 1.*
   - Save & download all images within a defined div to $images
   - Copy & save all content within a defined div to $content. $content is then broken down 
       and pulled apart based upon the content that is within it. Example:

     > > > - In stores: $date
     > > > - format: $format
     > > > - UPC: $upc
     > > > - Price: $price
     > > > - The Story: $story
3. Copy & save defined div hyperlink and save into $seriesinfo
4. Copy & save defined div $relatedinfo and then break it down.

   - images within $relatedinfo to $relatedimages
   - content within $relatedinfo to $relatedcontent
   - links within $relatedinfo to $relatedlink. $relatedlink will loop off and restart this process itself from 1.

Now that everything is broken apart and saved into it's own little pieces. I want WordPress to automatically create a post and then start assigning all this info into the post. Working something like this.

1. Check for existing post with same $title if does not exist place $title in title for post and page-name. If it exists abort script and move on to the next.
2. Remove numbers and alpha characters from $title and check for existence of category if it does not exist; create it and assign to post. If it exists assigns category to the post.
3. Check for existing category with value $format if exists assign to post, if not create & assign category to post.
4. upload images that were downloaded from $image into this post.
5. Check for images that contain the word "cover" and assign as featured image.

Also how this whole thing executes also. I don't want this running 24/7 - just once a week I would like this to execute by itself and automatically go to the websites in question and scrape the content and create the pages.

I'm not asking you guys to write out the whole darn thing for me; though I definitely won't object to it! Just help point me in the right directions to get this going. Over the past day I've read probably 30+ articles on pulling content and there's so many options from what I can tell that I just don't know where to begin or how to get the ball moving in the right direction with this.

***Updated Code***

Notes: So I've managed to successfully copy the content and paths for each block and instead of downloading the images just echoing them from their present location. Next up is actually automating the process to create a post in wordpress to dump the data into.

```
function scraping_comic()
{
// create HTML DOM
$html = file_get_html('http://page-on-site-to-scrape.com');

    // get block to scrape
    foreach($html->find('li.browse_result') as $article)
{
    // get title from block
    $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h4', 0)->find('span',0)->plaintext);
    // get title url from block
    $item['title_url'] = trim($article->find('h4', 0)->find('a.grid-hidden',0)->href);
    // get image from block
    $item['image_url'] = trim($article->find('img.main_thumb',0)->src);
    // get details from block
    $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p.browse_result_description_release', 0)->plaintext);
    // get sale info from block
    $item['on_sale'] = trim($article->find('.browse_comics_release_dates', 0)->plaintext);

$ret[] = $item;
}

// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);

return $ret;
}


// ===== The Code ====

$ret = scraping_comic();

if ( ! empty($ret))
{

// place main url for instance when hyperlinks and image srcs don't use the full path.
$scrape = 'http://site-to-scrape.com';

foreach($ret as $v)
{
    echo '<p><a href="'.$scrape.$v['title_url'].'">'.$v['title'].'</a></p>';
    echo '<p><img src="'.$v['image_url'].'"></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$v['details'].'</p>';
    echo '<p> '.$v['on_sale'].'</p>';
}

}
    else { echo 'Could not scrape page!'; }
?>
```

Comment: As for the first part of your question, do you know exactly what's the structure of the divs you want to fetch from?. The number of sites you're considering is moderate or large?. Would you mind to have to do some work if some page you're fetching from changes its structure?. Depending on those question, you might want to look at unsupervised, semi-supervised or manual wrappers.

Comment: Some of the sites are huge, as I will be pulling content in from all comic book publishers.  The structures from what I've looked at in all sites will be easy to navigate to as I'm just looking at pulling content, paths, and images that are contained in the divs. Since i want to pull info that is contained within divs if a website changes its structures I would assume all that would be required is changing paths/div class/id names in the code?

Comment: Well, I was asking about how many sites are you considering, not so much how many 'records' are contained in each of them. If there are, say, 10-15 sites, I guess that's not too bad, and indeed, it would be a matter of changing your wrapper, but more than that, it would be a nightmare to maintain. Either way, it's not so trivial to construct a good wrapper for each site as it requires a bit a programming experience. I'd suggest to focus on your first and second task (retrieving links and fetching content including previous and next links). You could use lxml or BeautifulSoup for that.

Comment: Actually it just occurred to me, that instead of going through this from multiple websites. I could just use one. There are multiple database websites that could do the job rather than pulling from each publisher's main site.  As for retrieving links and fetching content I've already succeeded in doing that. Using simple_html_dom.php

Comment: <?php  
    $html = file_get_html('http://thewebsite.com');  
    foreach($html->find('.result-row') as $article) {  
    $item['title'] = $article->find('h4', 0)->plaintext;  
    $item['intro'] = $article->find('.browse_result_description_release', 0)->plaintext ;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('.user_controls', 0)->plaintext;  
    $item['thumbsrc'] = $article->find('.main_thumb', 0)->plaintext;  
    $item['thumbpath'] = $article->find('.thumbnail', 0)->plaintext;  
    $articles[] = $item;  

    }  
    print_r($articles);  
    ?>

Comment: That code pulls the content thats listed on the being released thismonth page. I can pull the links from the page also, I just haven't figured out how to pull links that are only contained within a defined div. Then how to go to that link. Once there I assume I could use this php above; modified to pull the content off of that page. I'll look into LXML and beautifulsoup.

Comment: If you can reduce the number of sites to just a one or two aggregators , that simplifies a lot. I looked into simplehtmldom and it seems good. Don't you need something like this: // Find all <a> in <div id="somediv"> $links = $html->find('div#somediv a');

Comment: I've placed what i've done so far into the post,trying to figure out how to integrate into the script to use the image_url to go to the path and download the image into a folder, then create a new local source to display the image. No luck so far..

Comment: Nevermind - I just changed the code to echo the img src rather than downloading it to the website and displaying it locally. :p - Next up is automatically creating a page in wordpress for this data and dumping the data into the page...

Answer (score 1):

Typically, **no** this wouldn't be legal. Companies that share their data these days will implement an API you can call and use in your application (subject to their Terms of Use and Copyright Policy). They don't like you making automated requests that bog down their server and kill their bandwidth.

That being said, often times product information is available from other sources such as Amazon which **does** have an API.

This project you are describing has a lot of work to be done essentially customizing the WordPress CMS and would be less than trivial for someone without any programming experience. You might want to consider hiring a freelancer at [oDesk](http://www.odesk.com) or one of the many other freelance job boards.

Comment: I will contact the companies to verify. They all say reproduction for commercial use is prohibited; however, there's 1000's of websites that have these companies materials on their commercial websites.  As for outsourcing this to someone else it defeats the purpose. I'm a quick learner and there are huge benefits to learning these protocols which is why I'm willing to spend whatever time it takes to learning this.